# Query type not supported by Athena Iceberg at this time when creating partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, apache-iceberg

I'm running the following sql in Athena to create a partition

```
ALTER TABLE database.table ADD 
    PARTITION (partitionone='123', partitiontwo='456') 
    LOCATION 's3://<s3-bucket>/data/partitionone=123/partitiontwo=456';
```

but I'm getting an error `Query type not supported by Athena Iceberg at this time`

I've tried running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` as well but also getting the same error.

How do I create partitions on my Athena Iceberg table?

Iceberg Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE database.table (
  id int,
  name string,
  partitionone string,
  partitiontwo string)
PARTITIONED BY (`partitionone`, `partitiontwo`)
LOCATION 's3://<s3-bucket>/data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'table_type'='iceberg'
);
```

I've tried creating the table without the `PARTITIONED BY` but still getting the same generic error returned.

Answer (score 0):

For Alter commands in iceberge tables, Parition is not supported yet.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-managing-tables.html

You can try by creating a new one.
[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-creating-tables.html#querying-iceberg-creating-tables-query-editor

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dremio](https://www.dremio.com/get-started?utm_source=community&utm_medium=stackoverflow&utm_content=content&utm_campaign=alexmercedcontent&utm_term=iceberg+lakehouse+nessie) to update the partitioning and the changes should then take hold in Athena.

You can spin up a Dremio account for free and connect it your AWS Glue or S3 to run ALTER statements against those tables when needed and using Athena or Dremio for querying.

here is the docs on ALTER TABLE: https://docs.dremio.com/cloud/reference/sql/commands/alter-table/

```
{ ADD | DROP } PARTITION FIELD { <column_name> | <partition_transform> } String   Optional

ADD partitions the table data on the values in a single column or by using one of the partition-transformation functions. DROP drops the partition definition. These are the partition-transformation functions:

identity( <col> ): Explicitly specified identity transform.
year( <col> ): Partition by year. The column uses either the TIMESTAMP or DATE data type.
month( <ts_col> ): Partition by month. The column uses either the TIMESTAMP or DATE data type.
day( <ts_col> ): Partition by day. The column uses either the TIMESTAMP or DATE data type.
hour( <ts_col> ): Partition by hour. The column uses either the TIMESTAMP or DATE data type.
bucket( <count>, <col> ): Partition by hashed value into <count> buckets.
truncate( <length>, <col> ): Partition by truncated value. Strings are truncated to the specified length. Integer and biginteger values are truncated to bins (for example: truncate(10, i) produces 0, 10, 20, and so on).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "add" partitions to iceberg tables, partition metadata is created when new data with that specific partition is inserted into an iceberg table.

You can insert data into iceberg tables either insert into or merge into.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-updating-iceberg-table-data.html